# AS2 Wait to Return

Tags: php, actionscript-2, listeners

I'm working on an AS2 project. I currently have a function that links to some PHP packets. Basically, the packet is sent, then sends back some information based on the argument. Simple, really.

The issue is that the original function needs to return that data. So I need it to wait for the packet to come back in order to return. Except you cannot attach "return" as a function for a listener.

```
function handleReturnNicknameById(id)
{
    nFunctionComplete = 0;
    trace("api : handleGetSwidById");
    AIRTOWER.send(AIRTOWER.PLAY_EXT, "friends#getPlayerInfoById", [id], "str", SHELL.getCurrentServerRoomId());
    AIRTOWER.addListener('getPlayerInfoById', handleReturnNickname);
    while(nFunctionComplete < 700)
    {
        if(nickReady == true)
        {
            nFunctionComplete = 701;
            return(nickToReturn);
        }
        nFunctionComplete++;
    }
}
function handleReturnNickname(obj)
{
    AIRTOWER.removeListener('getPlayerInfoById', handleReturnNickname);
    obj.shift();
    nickToReturn = obj[1];
    nickReady = true;
}
```

This is the only idea I had for getting it to work. I understand it is horribly ineffective, which is why I'm asking for help here.

Ultimately the question is: in AS2, can you make the function "wait" before return?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are looking for, you can use a [callback function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000139.html) which will be called when your data is loaded. So your code be like this :

```
function handleReturnNicknameById(id:Number, callback:Function): Void
{
    AIRTOWER.send(AIRTOWER.PLAY_EXT, "friends#getPlayerInfoById", [id], "str", SHELL.getCurrentServerRoomId());
    AIRTOWER.addListener('getPlayerInfoById', handleReturnNickname);

    function handleReturnNickname(obj): Void
    {
        AIRTOWER.removeListener('getPlayerInfoById', handleReturnNickname);
        obj.shift();
        var nickToReturn = obj[1];

        // run the callback function and pass the needed data
        callback(nickToReturn);
    }

}

// this function is called only when data is loaded
function my_callback(data): Void 
{
    // here you can use your data
    trace('loaded data : ' + data);
}
```

And to execute all that :

```
handleReturnNicknameById(id, my_callback);
```

Hope that can help.